# WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, nemerle

Ok... I want to make win32api WriteProcessMemory works.

(***Just for learning winAPI on .Net platforms ! ^___^***)

I'm using Nemerle but the syntax is similar C# and I can read C# code sure.

So here is my **steps** :

1) get win api function

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
public static extern WriteProcessMemory
(hProcess : IntPtr, 
lpBaseAddress : int, 
lpBuffer : array[byte], 
nSize : int, 
lpNumberOfBytesWritten :  out int) : bool;
```

2) Open process, Get debug privileges ^_^ and ... call function

```
    def WriteToMem(ProcessHandle : IntPtr, BaseAddress : int, NewVal : array[byte]) : bool
    {
        mutable BytesWritten : int = 0;
        WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, BaseAddress, NewVal, NewVal.Length, out BytesWritten)
    }
```

3) parameters :

```
    PatchOptions.noerror = 
    if (this.textBox1.Text=="" && !this.checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wind header caption could not be empty");
        false
    }
    else
    if (this.textBox4.Text=="" && this.checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process Id could not be empty");
        false
    }
    else
    if (this.textBox2.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BaseAddress could not be empty");
        false
    }
    else
    if (this.textBox3.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NewValue could not be empty");
        false
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                PatchOptions.WinHeader=this.textBox4.Text.ToString();
                PatchOptions.window=false;
            }
            else
            {
                PatchOptions.WinHeader=this.textBox1.Text.ToString();
                PatchOptions.window=true;
            }
            PatchOptions.BaseAddress=Int32.Parse( this.textBox2.Text.ToString() );
            PatchOptions.NewValue=BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32.Parse(this.textBox3.Text.ToString()));
            this.Close();
            true
        }
        catch
        {
            e is Exception => MessageBox.Show("You entered incorrect values.");
            false
        } 
    }
```

4) call :

```
    def isinjected() : string
    {
    if (Options.PatchOptions.noerror)
    {
        try
        {
            Memory.Patch(Options.PatchOptions.WinHeader,Options.PatchOptions.BaseAddress,Options.PatchOptions.NewValue,Options.PatchOptions.window);
        }
        catch
        {
            | e is Exception => MessageBox.Show("Memory Patching error");
            ""
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Patch options Error");
        ""
    }
    }

    def injection = isinjected();
    unless (injection=="")
        this.label1.Text =injection;
```

5)  Notepad ShowStatus offset :D (for test)

```
00b550d2 - 89 35 2c c0 b5 00 - mov [00b5c02c],esi
00b5509d - 89 3d 2c c0 b5 00 - mov [00b5c02c],edi
```

6) Convert Hex to Dec using win Calc :
(here is trouble)

00b550d2 = B550D2 = 11882706 ... hope it's correct 
(that's base address I guess)
hm... what is NewValue ?
And how can I enter byte array as integer :S

help me please >_<

Comment: If you're just trying to learn .NET, you probably shouldn't be starting with `WriteProcessMemory`, which is extremely complicated and not generally useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of WriteProcessMemory use in Nemerle:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using WinApi;

[ Flags ]
enum AllocationType
{
    | Commit = 0x1000
}

[ Flags ]
enum ProcessAccess : int
{
    | VMOperation = 0x8
    | VMRead      = 0x10
    | VMWrite     = 0x20
}

[ Flags ]
enum MemoryProtection
{
    | ReadWrite = 0x04
}

module WinApi
{
    [ DllImport("kernel32.dll") ]
    public extern OpenProcess
        ( dwDesiredAccess : ProcessAccess
        , bInheritHandle  : bool
        , dwProcessId     : int
        ) : IntPtr;

    [ DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true) ]
    public extern VirtualAllocEx
        ( hProcess         : IntPtr
        , lpAddress        : IntPtr
        , dwSize           : uint
        , flAllocationType : AllocationType
        , flProtect        : MemoryProtection
        ) : IntPtr;

    [ DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true) ]
    public extern WriteProcessMemory
        ( hProcess               : IntPtr
        , lpBaseAddress          : IntPtr
        , lpBuffer               : array[byte]
        , nSize                  : uint
        , lpNumberOfBytesWritten : out int
        ) : bool;
}

def data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello World!\0");

def process = OpenProcess
    ( dwDesiredAccess
        = ProcessAccess.VMOperation
        | ProcessAccess.VMRead
        | ProcessAccess.VMWrite
    , bInheritHandle  = false
    , dwProcessId     = 0x00005394 // Notepad instance
    );
Console.WriteLine($"process: $process");

def memory = VirtualAllocEx
    ( hProcess         = process
    , lpAddress        = IntPtr.Zero
    , dwSize           = data.Length :> uint
    , flAllocationType = AllocationType.Commit
    , flProtect        = MemoryProtection.ReadWrite
    );
Console.WriteLine($"memory: $memory");

mutable bytesWritten;
_ = WriteProcessMemory
    ( hProcess               = process
    , lpBaseAddress          = memory
    , lpBuffer               = data
    , nSize                  = data.Length :> uint
    , lpNumberOfBytesWritten = out bytesWritten
    );
Console.WriteLine($"bytesWritten: $bytesWritten");
```

Comment: thank you very much :) what means "_ =" Pattern Matching ? :-/ Also nice to meet you - someone who can helps with Nemerle on Stack-overflow *__*

Comment: "_ =" is a way of saying that you don't need the result of an expression. If you do not assign the result of a non-void function to anything, the compiler will give you a warning.

Comment: Pretty much. In my experience, MessageBox.Show accounts for almost all of the uses of this construct. You could also write a void wrapper around MessageBox.Show.